# DRF PWT Postman detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, authenticationtoken

Отправляю запрос в Postman по адресу `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/`, перед этим генерируя токен с использованием username и password по адресу `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/token/obtain/`, но Postman выдаёт "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
      ...
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 15,

    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renders.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renders.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ],

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    )
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=20),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': False,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUDIENCE': None,
    'ISSUER': None,
    'JWK_URL': None,
    'LEEWAY': 0,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Token',),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
    'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',
    'TOKEN_USER_CLASS': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.models.TokenUser',

    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsAdminUser, IsAuthenticated
from api.permissions import IsAdminOrReadOnly, IsOwnerOrReadOnly

from author.models import Author
from book.models import Book
from order.models import Order
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from api.serializers import *


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('drf-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('token/obtain/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='obtain_token'),
    path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='refresh_token'),
    path('token/verify/', TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name='verify_token'),
]
```

Comment: Я пытался использовать стандартные токены, а так же пробовал использовать djoser, но результат был таким же. Лечилось это только добавлением authentication_classes и добавлением туда TokenAuthentication, но ведь это не нормальное поведение, все настройки указаны же на глобальном уровне...

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ошибку:
Так как я импортировал renderers из rest_frameword в settings.py, то drf не загружал настройки из словаря settings.REST_FRAMEWORK.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).